# Improving Network Performance for Gigabyte Connections

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, nas, windows-server-2012

Currently I am getting around 10Mb/s a second on transfers from machine to NAS. Is there a way to improve performance maybe by enabling Jumbo Frames? MTU Settings? Is there a way to properly configure those settings?

I disabled Remote Differential Compression under Windows Features and also done `netsh int tcp set global dca=enabled` and `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=enabled`

What else can I try and do?

EDIT:

- Ports are 1000Mb/s(SERVER) and 100MB/s(NAS) -- NO USB(ewww)
- Drives are SATA 3GB/s(SSDs and HDD)(RAID 1)
- NAS is RAID-X which is 2x4TBs

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 10MB/s not 10Mb/s. what are your nics link speed and duplex, and do you have any management interface on your network switch? how are the hard disks in your NAS connected to it ( (e)SATA1/2/3, USB, etc ), and what RAID if any is in use?

Comment: Have you tried setting the speed and duplex manually on all devices? If you are using auto, try manual and see if it helps.  Have seen an issue with some hardware. Easy to test.